# LESS on hover label update <i> on the same level

Tags: html, css, less

**Question:** I am trying to set the hover state of a `<i>` material-icons when I hover over a label on the same level of the `<i>`.

Below is my HTML & LESS (I am not sure if SO Code snippet supports LESS)

**Result:** when I run the below I am not able to get the  to update its color.

```css
  button.org_nav_btn {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 0 10px 3px 0;
  margin-right: 10px;
  label {
    color: white;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: 300;
    &:hover {
      i.navigate {
        font-size: 100px;
      }
    }
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<button type="button" id="org_profile_next" class="btn org_nav_btn  pull-right nav-next">
                <div class="ico-btn">
                    <i class="material-icons navigate">navigate_next</i>
                    <label>NEXT</label>
                </div>
            </button>
```

Comment: You can't adjust the `i` when hovering the `label` here because the `i` is above the `label` in the DOM. Change their order and then you would be able to use the `+` (adjacent sibling) selector. Or, alternately you can put the `:hover` on the `div` and change the `i` when the div is hovered on.

Comment: Thank you I will look into putting the hover on the div#btn-ico and doing it that way. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Or simply put the `i` inside the `label`.

Comment: Good point that too @MrLister.